# Dialog's object position Libgdx

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I have a Dialog :

```
Dialog dialog=new Dialog("",style);
dialog.setSize(400, 500);
dialog.setPosition(Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/2-200, Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/2-300);
```

I added a two button in it:

```
 dialog.button(stopButton);
 dialog.button(goButton);
```

My problem is that I  can not change the position of buttons, not even if the imposed manually the buttons remain in the same position.

how could I do to solve the problem?

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The buttons of a libgdx dialog get added to the [**ButtonTable**](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/ui/Dialog.html#getButtonTable--) of the Dialog, you can get this table by calling `getButtonTable()` method and then arrange the buttons like you would do it with any other `Table`.

The following code would place goButton below the stopButton for example:

```
dialog.button(stopButton);
dialog.getButtonTable().row();
dialog.button(goButton);
```

If you want to fine-tune the layout more, you could just add the buttons to the table and use some TableLayout methods, like for example the below code would add some padding:

```
dialog.getButtonTable().add(stopButton).pad(20);
dialog.getButtonTable().add(goButton).pad(20);
```

Comment: I'm having problems trying to construct a dialog with all the buttons aligned to the right of the dialog itself. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Yes, there is a way by using .right() method of the table cell. Please create a new question with your example Dialog @Daniele

Comment: Is there a way for aligning the Title of the Dialog too?

EDITED

solution found: getTitleTable.setAlignment(Align.center)

I'm sorry...I used .align instead of setAlignment