# LibGdx -- Vertical arrangement of items in the dialog

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I'm newcomer in LibGdx and I have the peice of code

```
new Dialog("Sound", game.skin) {
{
    text("Choose the sound");
    button("Classical", GameScreen.HitSound.CLASSICAL);
    button("IrenSound", GameScreen.HitSound.IREN);
    button("Farting", GameScreen.HitSound.FARTING);
}
```

Which gives me that

[image: Dialog]

As you can see, dialog's items don't fit. How I can make dialog's items to vertical arrangemnt, not horizontal? Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26074089/dialogs-object-position-libgdx

Comment: Thanks for answering. I got this